# Item are not displayed in listview

Tags: android

### The items are not being displayed in the listview

This is my arraylist code, it is not working, the items are not displayed in the listview, in MainActivity.class this is my code with no compilation error, and in Memes.class this is my constructor with its due getters and setters
I do not understand what the problem is.
Anyone have any idea what it could be?

Coding Main

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
MediaPlayer mp;
//private ArrayList<memes> jmemes = new ArrayList<memes>();
ArrayList<memes> item = new  ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.memes_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

    MainActivity jmemes = new MainActivity();

    jmemes.item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
    jmemes.item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));

    ArrayAdapter<memes> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            playSong(position);

        }
    });
}

public void playSong(int audios) {

    mp.reset();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, memes.getAudios());

    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}
```

}

Coding getters and setters

### Memes.class

```
 public class memes {
        private String nomes;
        private static int audios;

        public memes(String nome, int resID){

            this.nomes = nomes;
            this.audios = audios;
        }

        public String getNomes() {
            return nomes;
        }

        public void setNomes(String nomes) {
            this.nomes = nomes;
        }

        public static int getAudios() {
            return audios;
        }

        public static void setAudios(int audios) {
            memes.audios = audios;
        }
    }
```

[previous APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZInTw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with these lines

```
    MainActivity jmemes = new MainActivity();

    jmemes.item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
    jmemes.item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));
```

You do not need to instantiate an activity inside it's oncreate method. Instead edit your main class to look similar to this snippet

```
ArrayList<memes> item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.memes_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

    item = new ArrayList<>();

    item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
    item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));
```

One more thing. The default arrayadapter calls toString() on the class in question then sets the text of the view to that string, so to display what you want you need to define your own class that extends ArrayAdapter. There is a good answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: If you're data binding to a custom class, as you have, you need to define an adapter to appropriately display the information that you want from the class.

Comment: One more thing, your memes class has an error. In your constructor, you aren't setting the audios attribute. Look over your constructor and change audios to a non-static field.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem is :

```
MainActivity jmemes = new MainActivity();
```

you can work on the object directly, you have created in memory, a new Main Activity so you are working in another object different from the current object displayed. 
So try to remove it it will work fine.

Your code should be like :

```
item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));
```

Comment: Thanks works, but now I get errors on those lines. I want the item to play a sound when clicked.                

         public void playSong(int audios) {

          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, memes.getAudios());

          mp.start();
       }

Comment: can you put the Log ?

Comment: help plsssssssssssssssssssssssssss?